# How to stop browser auto scrolling containers on focus changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, html-input, tabbing

As you tab between input fields in a browser, the browser will automatically scroll the nearest parent container to place the next focused field within the view.

### Simple JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/pxyXZ/1/

```
$('.section').eq(6).find('input').focus();
```

For example if you open the above fiddle it selects "Sample item 7" at the bottom of the yellow window. If you press tab the "Sample text 8" field jumps up towards the middle of the parent window.

Obviously this is a great thing for normal websites, but I have a custom scrolling container in which I position & scroll everything manually. I am tracking focus changes and will use a momentum scroller to bring it into view, but **how do I disable the default scrolling behavior of web-browsers?** Happy to accept CSS, Javascript or JQuery solutions.

Comment: the first thing i think of is using `keyUp` detection to register tab, seeing if the next input is out of the "window", then using ur custom scroller with `$(':focus').parent().next().find('input').focus()` as a callback. what is your momentum scroller? does it allow for callback functions?

Comment: @PlantTheIdea: I wrote my own momentum scroller based loosely on this article: http://ariya.ofilabs.com/2011/10/flick-list-with-its-momentum-scrolling-and-deceleration.html and I do have callbacks.

Comment: alright, provided an answer. its generic because i don't have code to really work with, but the general gist is that you don't want to disable the scrolling behavior of browsers, you want to postpone the focus change until after you've performed your own scrolling. this will allow you to control the scrolling as you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you can't smooth scroll for focus changes as the events happen in the wrong order. You get an awful delay while it scrolls the field into view, before focus is set. A better *move* of the item onscreen, or superfast scroll, is all we can hope for.

As suggested by PlantTheIdea (+1'ed), you need to catch the TAB key and find the next focusable item, bring it into view, then set focus to it.

In practice there are a number of issues to resolve:

- Change of focus occurs on TAB keydown (not keyup).
- Only match non-hidden inputs (lots of web apps have hidden fields that will go bang if you try to focus them).
- Allow for the selection to tab off the first or last item on the page (otherwise the browser loses the ability to tab to its address bar)
- use `e.keyCode || e.which` to allow for older browsers
- catch event at document level to allow for cases of other inputs, outside of the scrolling area, causing it to enter the scrolling area (first or last input).

### The final code looks like this:

```
$(document).on('keydown', ':focus', function (event)
{
    if ((event.keyCode || event.which) == 9)
    {
        var $inputs = $(":input:not(hidden)")
        var index = $inputs.index(this);
        // Index previous or next input based on the shift key
        index += event.shiftKey ? -1 : 1;
        // If we are in the range of valid inputs (else browser takes focus)
        if (index >= 0 && index < $inputs.length)
        {
            var $next = $inputs.eq(index);
            event.preventDefault();
            // Move, not scroll, to the next/prev item....
            MoveIntoView($next);
            $next.focus();
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: just a heads up, you can use the `tabindex` attribute to explicitly declare the order of tab processing. This should help with the hidden inputs piece, and also allows for checking if first or last item on page (e.g., `if($(this).attr('tabindex') < 10)`).

Comment: @PlantTheIdea: `tabindex` is not correctly supported across all browsers but in this instance we just want to work with the authored order and as our content is generated dynamically (including partial pages) I would not want to specify the tab order explicitly unless absolutely need. Thanks for pointing it out though, as any existing tabindex values would currently be ignored by the above code. As far as hidden inputs go, best to ignore/exclude them anyway. We do a lot of MVC apps which are full of hidden inputs. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

This is just winging it based on my comment above:

```
$('input').on('keyup',function(e){
    if(e.keyCode === 9) {
        var $this = $(this);

        // (do your scroll thing here
        // ..., function(){
            $this.parent().next().find('input').focus();
        // });
    }
});
```

Long as the callback timing is correct, this will only change focus after you have already scrolled. You'll need to do your own magic to determine what to scroll to, but this should give you the focus behavior you want.

Comment: Has to be on `keydown` as the focus change occurs on `keydown`, not `keyup`. Also need to reverse direction on shift-tab and use a more generic selector for the next input (but aside from all that you are on the right track). Almost finished implementing your ideas. Thanks :)

Comment: yeah i mean i figured it would need some tweaking, it was more a general idea to run with. hope it works out for you!

Comment: +1 for giving me the right idea. Have posted exact solution as it may help others. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.